# Update area column after changes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'am using QGIS and POSTGIS, for example to automatically calculate the area of a new created polygon. I do that with following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_area()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
NEW.fla_ha := st_area(NEW.geom)/10000;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON nutzungen
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_area();
```

**Problem definition:**

How do I change my trigger, so that editings at the geometry of a existing polygon (new vertex ...) will be recognized and the old area value will be overwritten.

If I use **UPDATE** in combination with an **AFTER-TRIGGER**  it updates my whole fla_ha column and not the specific row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "area_new"()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
UPDATE nutzungen SET fla_ha=ST_AREA(NEW.geom)/10000;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

ALTER FUNCTION "area_new"()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: The code looks correct for your expectations, but your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original trigger contains an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate **BEFORE** INSERT OR UPDATE ON nutzungen
```

This means that you're triggers calls the function on geom **before** the geometry is updated. Replace the trigger by calling the following:

```
DROP TRIGGER area_calculate;
CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON nutzungen
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_area();
```

As for the `calc_area()` function, no need to give it a new name! `CREATE OR REPLACE` means that when you run the create script for the new function, it will **replace** the old one.

Comment: I have followed your instruction, with no success. Only if i use the argument **BEFORE** in 'CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON nutzungen' my new added polygon gets an area value. Argument **AFTER** affects no calculation for new added polygons and  no recalculation for edited polygons. The field remains empty.

Comment: Now I have changed it again according your hints and it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement is correct in what you're trying to achieve - at least testing on my PostgreSQL 9.3 server. Let me explain:

- The trigger fires `BEFORE` the changes are applied to the table.
- In this state, it already has information about the `OLD` content of the row and the `NEW` content of the row (i.e. how the row will look like after the changes implied in the `UPDATE` will have been applied), given it's fired during an `UPDATE`; for an `INSERT`, of course, only the `NEW` information exists.
- The `NEW` content has not yet been written to the table, thus can be intercepted.
- So, by setting `NEW.fla_ha=st_area(NEW.geom)/10000`, you fiddle inside the row information that's yet to be applied to the table.
- By `RETURN NEW`, you give the entire, customized-by-your-function row back, which is then applied to the table - which means, including your st_area calculation

With an `AFTER` trigger, it doesn't work as you'd expect it because the changes have already been pyhsically applied to the table row. So any interception in the `NEW` row is simply disregarded. The `NEW` object exists in this context for further evaluation, but changes to it are not applied anymore to the table.

Hope this makes it quite clear.

Comment: ... it is still an open question to me how the whole sequence of scripts would look like for handling just the one object that has a modified geometry. the insert statement and the role of trigger before vs. trigger after is comprehensible. but I think concerning the "area new" function some parts are missing

Comment: ... i tried to figure it out with the following code:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recalc_area_func_for_existing_o()
RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'OLD.id: %, NEW.id: %', OLD.id, nEW.id;
    IF OLD.id = NEW.id THEN
        UPDATE st_steph_01.wmf_polyg_31256 
        SET area = ROUND(st_area(NEW.geom)::numeric,4)
        WHERE id = OLD.id;
    END IF; 
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
... but I am running into a recursive loop with that update. the trigger function has a "BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable" statement

Comment: @roberttuw Don't put an UPDATE inside the FUNCTION. The FUNCTION should not do anything in the database, but return the final values for the row. The rest is handled by the trigger logic itself. So in your case:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recalc_area_func_for_existing_o() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF OLD.id = NEW.id THEN NEW.area = ROUND(st_area(NEW.geom)::numeric,4); RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON st_steph_01.wmf_polyg_31256 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE recalc_area_func_for_existing_o();